# To which port is a process attached in Linux

Tags: linux, port, jonas

I want to know which port is my Jonas, on which a Java project has been deployed, is attached to in a Linux server.  I have the pid of the Jonas and tried netstat -lnp but I found no port attached to that PID. 
Any idea of how to do this.

Comment: `sudo netstat -tulpen | grep THE_PID`

Comment: `ss -p | grep pid=57955`

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal application i.e. shell prompt.
Run any one of the following command:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN   
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN  
sudo nmap -sTU -O IP-address-Here
```

lsof command

The syntax is:

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n  
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN  
$ doas lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN ### [OpenBSD] ###
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do, I prefer this

```
sudo netstat -pan |grep pid
```

Also, you can use

```
sudo lsof -Pan -p pid -i
```

`pid` should be actual "pid" number that you have